# Calculating Finite Sum in SQL?

Tags: sql, math, while-loop, sum, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to figure out a way in which to calculate the following in SQL:

[image: Formula]

Where r and W is static (0.2 , 0.4) respectively.
The x resembles age, and does never exceed 68.

My Database has columns for x, r and W, where x is different for each observation.

My initial thought was a while loop, but i'm not able to construct a while loop, that does something like :

```
select * , 0 as n

while n < 68 - (x + 1)
begin
    (POWER((1 + r) / (1 + W)) , n)
    set n = n + 1
end

from data
```

Hopefully the pseudo-code above illustrates what i am trying to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Should be easy with a stored function, but how this looks like  depends on the rdbms...

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, if that is any help

Comment: This is a frontend, but it indicates you are using SQL Server, but which version... Try `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: @Amby95 please share some sample data and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a loop. Your sum (given r,w,x) is

```
(POWER( (1+r)/(1+w), 68-x)-1)/( (1+r)/(1+w) - 1)
```

unless

```
(1+r)/(1+w) == 1
```

in which case the sum is 68-x

For if we write

```
c = (1+r)/(1+w) and 
N = 68-x
```

then

```
(c-1)*Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow(c,n)}
= c*Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow(c,n)} - Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow(c,n)}
= Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow( c, n+1)} - Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow(c,n)}
= Sum{ 1<=n<=N | pow( c, n)} - Sum{ 0<=n<N | pow(c,n)}
= pow( C, N) - 1 (as all the other terms cancel)
```